# LaTeX table positioning

Tags: latex

I have a LaTeX document that contains a paragraph followed by 4 tables followed by a second paragraph. I want the 4 tables to appear between the two paragraphs which from what I've [read](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables#The_table_environment_-_captioning_etc) means I should use the [h] option after beginning the table environment (e.g. `\begin{table}[h]`).

Using this the first two tables appear after paragraph 1 as expected, however paragraph 2 is then displayed with the last two tables appearing on the following page. How can I get the tables to appear in the correct location?

I've tried various things to correct the positioning such as using `[h!]` however this doesn't seem  to have any effect. Using `\clearpage` after the tables does have the desired effect of making the tables appear before the second paragraph but it then leaves the last two tables on their own page with loads of white-space, when I would prefer to have the second paragraph begin immediately after the tables.

```
Paragraph 1...

\begin{table}[h]
    table1...
\end{table}

\begin{table}[h]
   table2...
\end{table}[h]
...

Paragraph 2...
```

Comment: The order of (all of) the letters in the optional argument has no effect.

Comment: @Gacek, I bet Will Robertson is right. According to http://mintaka.sdsu.edu/GF/bibliog/latex/floats.html, "[t]he arguments in brackets tell LaTeX where it's possible to put the float; their order is unimportant."

Comment: This is only slightly related, but I feel that it is important to know: The [h] option should never be used alone, and in fact, newer LaTeX versions replace it with [ht] automatically. That might have been your problem as well.
You can read more in [this guide](ftp://ftp.rrzn.uni-hannover.de/pub/mirror/tex-archive/info/epslatex/english/epslatex.pdf) in section 17.2 "Figure Placement".

Comment: @Gacek `[h!]` is the correct version. It's the equivalent to `[H]`.  Both require the `float` package.

Comment: The TeX stack exchange canonical answer for this question is: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39017/107497

Answer (score 285, accepted):

After doing some more googling I came across the *float* package which lets you prevent LaTeX from repositioning the tables.

In the preamble:

```
\usepackage{float}
```

Then for each table you can use the `H` placement option (e.g. `\begin{table}[H]`) to make sure it doesn't get repositioned.

Comment: In case someone is using org-mode, put this on top:

```#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{float}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \restylefloat{table}```

And then,
```#+CAPTION: A table
#+NAME: tab:table-label
#+ATTR_LATEX: :placement [H] :center t
<<actual table content>>
``` Excuse the poor newline formatting in comments.

Comment: Sorry, but the claim that it's necessary to run `\restylefloat{table}` in order to use the `[H]` positioning specifier is **false**. One should only ever run `\restylefloat{table}` if one has first run the package instructions `\floatstyle`, `\floatplacement`, or `\floatname`. Please update your answer to *remove* the reference to `\restylefloat`. In case you need more proof that running `\restylefloat` routinely is not a good idea, do see the posting [Caption and label of a table, of two tables kept side by side, is assigned to another table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/564403/5001).

Answer (score 66):

## Table Positioning

### Available Parameters

A table can easily be placed with the following parameters:

- `h` Place the float **here**, i.e., approximately at the same point it occurs in the source text (however, not exactly at the spot)
- `t` Position at the **top** of the page.
- `b` Position at the **bottom** of the page.
- `p` Put on a special **page** for floats only.
- `!` Override internal parameters LaTeX uses for determining "good" float positions.
- `H` Places the float at **precisely the location** in the LATEX code. Requires the float package. This is somewhat equivalent to `h!`.

If you want to make use of `H` (or `h!`) for an exact positioning, make sure you got the `float` package correctly set up in the preamble:

```
\usepackage{float}
\restylefloat{table}
```

### Example

If you want to place the table at the same page, either at the exact place or at least at the top of the page (what fits best for the latex engine), use the parameters `h` and `t` like this:

```
\begin{table}[ht]
    table content ...
\end{table}
```

---

Sources: [Overleaf.com](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Positioning_images_and_tables#Positioning_tables)

Comment: For me, `H` works for placing the table at **precisely the location**, but `h!`  doesn't. Not sure `H` is equivalent to `h!` in that case.

Answer (score 40):

At the beginning with the `usepackage` definitions include:

```
\usepackage{placeins}
```

And before and after add:

```
\FloatBarrier
\begin{table}[h]
    \begin{tabular}{llll}
      .... 
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\FloatBarrier
```

This places the table exactly where you want in the text.

Answer (score 12):

Here's an easy solution, from [Wikibooks](http://en.wikibooks.org):

> The placeins package provides the command \FloatBarrier, which can be used to prevent floats from being moved over it.

I just put `\FloatBarrier` before and after every table.

Comment: Amazing workaround!

Answer (score 9):

What happens if the text plus tables plus text doesn't fit onto a single page? By trying to force the typesetting in this way, you are very likely to end up with pages that run too short; i.e., because a table cannot by default break over a page it will be pushed to the next, and leave a gap on the page before. You'll notice that you never see this in a published book.

The floating behaviour is a Good Thing! I recommend using `[htbp]` as the default setting for all tables and figures until your document is complete; only then should think about fine-tuning their precise placement.

P.S. Read the [FAQ](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=floats); most other answers here are partial combinations of advice given there.

Comment: The floating behavior avoids leaving space, but moving figures away makes life harder for the reader. For this reason Edward Tufte, an important designer, recommends integrating text and figures/tables - in his published books, he does not refer to tables by number. "See Table 1" does not appear, since the table is just there. He just places them at the right place - mid-sentence. I guess that means doing more work to lay out the tables but less work for the readers.

Comment: @Blaisorblade — sure, and there are other such notable examples, but I propose that writing a text in such a way is an order of magnitude more difficult for most people than using floats. You're talking about discarding 99% of book design for an unachievable optimum. Consider the point I made in my answer: ‘what if a table can't fit beneath the text?’ In your scenario have to redesign or rewrite, and this is untenable in many situations.

Comment: Well, we agree on what the optimum is-and yes, most often it's practically unachievable. In day-to-day life I also usually stick to floats. But I do have small tables and figures inline, and it works rather nicely (provided I check the final version-which is easy only because I have documents of at most 20 pages). I just see floating as a Reasonable Tradeoff rather than a Good Thing :-).

Comment: What is the difference between setting `[htbp]` as opposed to nothing at all?

Comment: @WaldirLeoncio at least for me, nothing at all defaults to a `[ht]` rather than `[htbp]`

Answer (score 6):

If you want to have two tables next to each other you can use: (with `float` package loaded)

```
\begin{table}[H]
 \begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
  %first table
 \end{minipage}
 \begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
  %second table
 \end{minipage}
\end{table}
```

Each one will have own caption and number.
Another option is `subfigure` package.

Answer (score 6):

In my case I was having an issue where the table was not being displayed right after the paragraph I inserted it, so I simply changed

```
\begin{table}[]
```

to

```
\begin{table}[ht]
```

Answer (score 4):

You may want to add this to your preamble, and adjust the values as necessary:

```
 %------------begin Float Adjustment
%two column float page must be 90% full
\renewcommand\dblfloatpagefraction{.90}
%two column top float can cover up to 80% of page
\renewcommand\dbltopfraction{.80}
%float page must be 90% full
\renewcommand\floatpagefraction{.90}
%top float can cover up to 80% of page
\renewcommand\topfraction{.80}
%bottom float can cover up to 80% of page
\renewcommand\bottomfraction{.80}
%at least 10% of a normal page must contain text
\renewcommand\textfraction{.1}
%separation between floats and text
\setlength\dbltextfloatsep{9pt plus 5pt minus 3pt }
%separation between two column floats and text
\setlength\textfloatsep{4pt plus 2pt minus 1.5pt}
```

Particularly, the \floatpagefraction may be of interest.

Answer (score 2):

Not necessary to use  `\restylefloat` and destroys other options, like caption placement. just use `[H]` or `[!h]` after `\begin{table}`.

Comment: answer is hard to understand, try to give more details.

Comment: The answer above says to use \usepackage{float} and \restylefloat{table} but the second is unnecessary and causes unexpected difficulties. the first is all that is needed.