# Hold table position in R-markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I'm trying to insert a table in Rmarkdown, but i just can't hold the position of the table. I don't have a lot of experience with Rmarkdown and maybe the problem may be something stupid that I missed.

```
---
title: "Rmarkdown document"
author: "Me"
output: pdf_document
header-includes:
 - \usepackage{float}
 - \floatplacement{figure}{H}
fig_caption: yes
---
```

````
```{r load-packages, include=FALSE, echo=TRUE}
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(gtools)
library(gdata)
library(formattable)
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)
library(scales)
library(jpeg)
library(grid)
library(devtools)
library(easyGgplot2)

knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE, message = FALSE, warning = FALSE, fig.pos = "H")
options("scipen"=100, "digits"=0)
````

The loop is commented for the sake of doing one table for the example.

```
{r, results='asis',fig.cap='',out.extra = ''}

#for (k in  1:length(BASES)){

k <- 1
cat("\\newpage")
 print(names(BASES[k]))
cat('\n\n<!-- -->\n\n')

#for (i in 1:(ncol(BASES[[k]]) - x)){
i <- 1

print(names(Estadisticas[[k]][i]))

print(knitr::kable(Estadisticas[[k]][i],align = "c")) 

print( ggplot(BASES[[k]], aes(x= BASES[[k]][,i+x], fill=ano)) + geom_density(alpha=.2) + 
   scale_x_continuous(name=names(Estadisticas[[k]][i]),limits = c(1,max(Estadisticas[[k]][[i]][["media_sin_0"]],na.rm = T) + 3*max(Estadisticas[[k]][[i]][["sd"]],na.rm = T)),labels = scales::comma) +  
scale_y_continuous(name="DENSIDAD"))

cat("\\newpage")
#}

#}
```

[PDF output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/93IHs.png) with the tabble at the top, but I would like it to be between Title 1.1 and the graph.

I used (I think I used, I may be wrong ) the input of [this answer by Yihui Xie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42486617/knitr-ignoring-fig-pos/43245550#43245550).

I used [this input](https://community.rstudio.com/t/how-do-i-specify-h-for-hold-position/25963).

I also tried using

```
print(knitr::kable(Estadisticas[[k]][i],align = "c")%>% kable_styling(latex_options = "hold_position"))

print(knitr::kable(Estadisticas[[k]][i],align = "c")%>% kable_styling(latex_options = "HOLD_position"))
```

My session info

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.6.2 (2019-12-12)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 17763)

Matrix products: default

attached base packages:
[1] grid      stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] easyGgplot2_1.0.0.9000 ggplot2_3.2.1          devtools_2.2.2         usethis_1.5.1         
 [5] jpeg_0.1-8.1           scales_1.1.0           kableExtra_1.1.0       knitr_1.28            
 [9] formattable_0.2.0.1    gdata_2.18.0           gtools_3.8.1           tidyr_1.0.2           
[13] dplyr_0.8.4           

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.3        prettyunits_1.1.1 ps_1.3.2          assertthat_0.2.1  rprojroot_1.3-2  
 [6] digest_0.6.25     R6_2.4.1          backports_1.1.5   evaluate_0.14     httr_1.4.1       
[11] pillar_1.4.3      rlang_0.4.5       lazyeval_0.2.2    rstudioapi_0.11   callr_3.4.2      
[16] rmarkdown_2.1     desc_1.2.0        webshot_0.5.2     readr_1.3.1       stringr_1.4.0    
[21] htmlwidgets_1.5.1 munsell_0.5.0     compiler_3.6.2    xfun_0.12         pkgconfig_2.0.3  
[26] pkgbuild_1.0.6    htmltools_0.4.0   tidyselect_1.0.0  tibble_2.1.3      fansi_0.4.1      
[31] viridisLite_0.3.0 crayon_1.3.4      withr_2.1.2       gtable_0.3.0      lifecycle_0.1.0  
[36] magrittr_1.5      cli_2.0.2         stringi_1.4.6     fs_1.3.1          remotes_2.1.1    
[41] testthat_2.3.2    xml2_1.2.2        ellipsis_0.3.0    vctrs_0.2.3       tools_3.6.2      
[46] glue_1.3.1        purrr_0.3.3       hms_0.5.3         processx_3.4.2    pkgload_1.0.2    
[51] yaml_2.2.1        colorspace_1.4-1  sessioninfo_1.1.1 rvest_0.3.5       memoise_1.1.0
```

Pd 1. This is my first question :D

Pd 2. Sorry for the broken english.

Pd 3. I am high on caffeine and frustration, please help.

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1673942

Comment: [This section](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/figure-placement.html) from the `R Markdown Cookbook` might be helpful.

Comment: see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53153537/rmarkdown-setting-the-position-of-kable) too